# CASE within IN with multiple values not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am testing with a CASE statement. I want to have the values within 'IN' to change base on the Code value

This works

```
WITH test(Part, Code) AS (
    SELECT '001', 'A' UNION SELECT '002', 'A' UNION
    SELECT '003', 'A' UNION SELECT '004', 'B' UNION
    SELECT '005', 'B' UNION SELECT '006', 'B')
SELECT * FROM test WHERE Part IN (CASE Code
    WHEN 'A' THEN '001'
    WHEN 'B' THEN '004'
    END)
```

'IN' can be replaced with '=' here and is used just for comparison to the following code

This doesn't work

```
WITH test(Part, Code) AS (
    SELECT '001', 'A' UNION SELECT '002', 'A' UNION
    SELECT '003', 'A' UNION SELECT '004', 'B' UNION
    SELECT '005', 'B' UNION SELECT '006', 'B')
SELECT * FROM test WHERE Part IN (CASE Code
    WHEN 'A' THEN '001', '002'
    WHEN 'B' THEN '004', '005'
    END)
```

SSMS complains about the ','. How do you fix the code above?

I will pick the one with minimal changes as the answer.

### Edited

Someone asked for an equivalent code to what I wanted to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE
    (Code = 'A' AND Part IN ('001', '002'))
    OR
    (Code = 'B' AND Part IN ('004', '005'))
    OR
    (Code = 'C' AND Part IN ('007', '008'))
    OR
    (Code = 'D' AND Part IN ('010', '011'))
```

Clearly, I wanted to avoid repeating the same pattern over and over by combining them into a CASE statement:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE Part IN (<case statement>)
```

I know there are other ways to find the results, but this question is about making the query nice and clean using CASE and IN with multiple values, not how to find the results. Feel free to answer "Impossible" with explanation if that is the case and I will pick that as the answer.

Comment: It seems a bit unclear what you want to achieve. Please post an expected result.

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* that returns a single *scalar* value (per row). I suspect that `CASE` is just getting in your way and it would be better to express the conditions using simple boolean logic (with `AND` and `OR`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. As I said in the comments, `CASE` returns a *single* scalar value.

My own suggestion for how to fix it would be to place the search conditions in another table and then just use `EXISTS` with a subquery:

```
WITH test(Part, Code) AS (
    SELECT '001', 'A' UNION SELECT '002', 'A' UNION
    SELECT '003', 'A' UNION SELECT '004', 'B' UNION
    SELECT '005', 'B' UNION SELECT '006', 'B')
, conditions (Code,Part) as (
    SELECT 'A','001' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A','002' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B','004' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B','005')
SELECT * FROM test t WHERE EXISTS
     (SELECT * FROM conditions c where
           t.Part = c.Part and
           t.Code = c.Code)
```

Which hopefully fulfils your desire to avoid repetition.

---

This is also why I'd usually encourage people to give us the overall problem to solve, not the problem with the solution to an (unknown problem) - `CASE` is just absolutely the wrong tool for this job, so any solution that *does* manage to use `CASE` is going to be ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect if CASE can help you

Try using conditional clause as:

```
WITH test(Part, Code) AS (
  SELECT '001', 'A' UNION SELECT '002', 'A' UNION
  SELECT '003', 'A' UNION SELECT '004', 'B' UNION
  SELECT '005', 'B' UNION SELECT '006', 'B')

SELECT * FROM test WHERE
  (Code <> 'A' OR Part IN ('001', '002'))
  AND
  (Code <> 'B' OR Part IN ('004', '005'))
```